# Continue modifying DOM as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, infinite-scroll

I have a chrome extension that modifies the DOM based on keywords. The problem is, for websites like twitter that have an infinite scroll, I need a way for my function to keep firing as the user scrolls through the page.

Is `.livequery()` the only way to do this or is there a better way?

Right now all of the logic is plain JavaScript/Jquery, but I'm open to using a framework like Angular if that's the best way to do it.

```
I have several functions that interact -
1) a hide() function that adds a class to divs containing words I want hidden
2) a walk() function that walks the DOM and identifies divs to call hide() on
3) walkWithFilter() function that gets words to filter from localstorage and calls walk() function
```

The last function `walkWithFilter()` is called in a `window.onload()` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `onScroll` event would be a natural match for this. The trick would be that you'd need to keep track of what's already been processed to avoid reprocessing old content. If you're assuming that the user is always exposing new content below the existing content, that could be as simple as keeping a pointer to the last processed item and restarting the `walkWithFilter` method from there. That doesn't seem like an entirely safe assumption to me, though.

If you want to be more robust in that regard, you could try a virtual DOM approach: you maintain a copy of the DOM as you last saw it, compare it to the DOM as it currently exists, and take a diff. I know there are a bunch of [premade libraries](https://github.com/fiduswriter/diffDOM) for this kind of thing, but I haven't used any and can't recommend a specific one (the link just goes to the first example that showed up in Google). It also doesn't appear to be overly burdensome to [roll your own](https://medium.com/@deathmood/how-to-write-your-own-virtual-dom-ee74acc13060#.3vw1v3kq1), if you're so inclined.